# Which atom python linting packages are stable?

Tags: python, atom-editor, flake8

It seems that there are too many Python linting packages and I am wonder which one should we use.

I suspect installing two will provide a confusing experience, if not even triggering weird bugs.

- [python-autopep8](https://atom.io/packages/python-autopep8) - 20+
- [linter-python-flaks](https://atom.io/packages/linter-python-pyflakes) - 6+
- [linter-flake8](https://atom.io/packages/linter-flake8) - 153+
- [linter-pylint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-pylint) - 119+

Here are few areas I want to clarify:

- is ok to use more than one?
- wouldn't be better to ask authors to join efforts and focus on a single one?
  What are the pros and cons for them?

Comment: I think pylint it the most common. In all professional projects I've seen, we always used pylint. It works well.

Comment: From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions asking us to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: BTW, pylint and flake8 (which combines pyflakes and pep8) are different lint tools, and autopep8 automatically formats Python code according to PEP 8.

Comment: I'm a year late to this question, but pylama wraps most of those tools and has a linter in Atom.

Comment: [**linter-python**](https://atom.io/packages/linter-python) use pylama that as @CraigKelly said use most of those tools.

Comment: I've tested most of them on my Atom in Windows 10. Unfortunately, most of them are not stable. I can't find any one which is working. There is no error message either.